# Problem with retrieving channel identifier - Discord.JS

Tags: javascript

**I have something like this ...**

```
  const channel = await message.guild.createChannel("channel-name", {
    type: 'text',
      permissionOverwrites: [{
      id: message.guild.id,
      deny: ['SEND_MESSAGES','SEND_TTS_MESSAGES']
    }]
  }).then(channel => {
    channel.setTopic("Topic")
  });

  const loc = "./data/test.json";
  let data = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(loc));
  data = {
    channel.id
  };

  fs.writeFileSync(loc, JSON.stringify(data, null, 2), (err) => {
    if(err) console.log(err)
  });
```

I want to save the channel ID "channel-name" in a json file, but I get this error

> (node:16060) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
>
> Languages: discord.js, node.js

Comment: Which line is the error on?

Answer (score 0):

The error means the the variable prior `.id` cannot be found or is undefined. However, it can also mean that the variable does not contain that path. That is the problem here. The path to id that you wrote was `channel.id`, however, the id var is actually at `channel.permissionOverwrites[0].id`. 

Channel > permissionOverwrites (first element of arr) > id value

Update this section of your code and you shouldn't have a problem:

```
  const loc = "./data/test.json";
  let data = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(loc));
  data = {
    channel.permissionOverwrites[0].id // Change path to id
  };
```